# Login urls not working for google PHP SDK

Tags: php, google-app-engine, authentication, sdk, logout

I m trying to create a login and log out I used the code from here

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/users/loginurls?hl=vi

So my code looks like

```
    <?php
require_once 'google/appengine/api/users/User.php';
require_once 'google/appengine/api/users/UserService.php';


use google\appengine\api\users\User;
use google\appengine\api\users\UserService;

$user = UserService::getCurrentUser();

if (isset($user)) {
    echo sprintf('Welcome, %s! (sign out)',
        $user->getNickname(),
        UserService::createLogoutUrl('/'));
} else {
    echo sprintf('Sign in or register',
        UserService::createLoginUrl('/'));
}
```

and my app.yaml

```
application: test
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /scripts
  static_dir: scripts

- url: .*
  script: main.php
  login: required
  auth_fail_action: redirect
```

When I run the app locally using Google PHP SDK 1.8.1 I get a lot of errors and the page does not load.

```
ERROR:root:php failure (255) with:

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  in <b>D:\google_appengine 1.8.1\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\RemoteApiProxy.php</b> on line <b>92</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(http://localhost:56354): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  in <b>D:\google_appengine 1.8.1\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\RemoteApiProxy.php</b> on line <b>92</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'google\net\ProtocolBufferDecodeError' with message 'Not initialized: logout_url' in D:\google_appengine 1.8.1\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\proto\ProtocolMessage.php:121
Stack trace:
#0 D:\google_appengine 1.8.1\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\proto\ProtocolMessage.php(88): google\net\ProtocolMessage-&gt;mergeFromString('')
#1 D:\google_appengine 1.8.1\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\RemoteApiProxy.php(109): google\net\ProtocolMessage-&gt;parseFromString('')
#2 D:\google_appengine 1.8.1\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\ApiProxy.php(42): google\appengine\runtime\RemoteApiProxy-&gt;makeSyncCall('user', 'CreateLogoutURL', Object(google\appengine\CreateLogoutURLRequest), Object(google\appengine\CreateLogoutURLResponse), NULL)
#3 D:\google_appengine 1.8.1\php\sdk\google\appengine\api\users\UserService.php(95): google\appengine\runtime\ApiProxy::makeSyncCall('user', 'CreateLogoutURL', Object(google\appengine\CreateLogoutURLRequest), Object(google\appengine\CreateLogoutURLResponse))
#4 D:\Google PHP\ in <b>D:\google_appengine 1.8.1\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\proto\ProtocolMessage.php</b> on line <b>121</b><br />

INFO     2013-06-20 22:00:49,384 server.py:593] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Any idea what is breaking in the SDK.

When I run the app from server it is not creating the sign out link [image: No link created]

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing in appspot is because you are not actually including the generated links in the html.

Compare the example:

```
'Welcome, %s! (<a href="%s">sign out</a>)'
```

with your code:

```
'Welcome, %s! (sign out)'
```

Comment: That worked for the missing link.
Now can you help me run this locally on the development server. 

I am still getting the error when I run 


>D:\google_appengine 1.8.1>dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=D:\PHP\php-cgi.exe "D:\Google PHP"

Comment: D:\google_appengine 1.8.1>dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=D:\PHP\php-cgi.exe "D:\Google PHP"  I was not able to get this in code block